# Removing bezel from vector in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, vector

I would like to place this vector image against the side. There is no white space at the top, so it is possible to place it against the top edge. On the left, right and at the bottom there is white space. How can I remove this white space?

[Image showing the problem. The arrows indicate the white space that I want to eliminate.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgYwv.png)

Here is the xml-code for my vector

```
<vector android:autoMirrored="true" android:height="418dp"
android:viewportHeight="418" android:viewportWidth="438"
android:width="480dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#FB5A5A" android:pathData="M9,0h420v278h-420z"/>
<path android:fillColor="#d54646" android:pathData="M9,277h420v131h-420z"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there is margin of 9 dp in left and bottom so

change to `android:pathData="M0,0h420v278h-420z"` and `android:pathData="M0,277h420v140h-420z"`

**If you want explanation**

`M9,0` says go to `9` in `x` and `0` in y direction from origin where origin is top left corner because you don't want to travel any distance in x so change to 0 also the height is `418` so the total height of first and second rectangle should add up to `418` to fill it up, but `v278` makes height of first rectangle `278` and `v131` makes height of second rectangle `131` and `278 + 131 = 409` so we make is `v140` now `278 + 140 = 418` so it fill entire space and you get no margins left

**Have a good day**